# How to write a csv from a numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

data = [[1 2 3 4][5 6 7 8][9 10 11 12]]

The object I receive has this structure. The numbers in each sub-array aren't separated

I've tried to convert into a list and then split it but it writes separated rows

simMatrix = open(ficheroDestino, 'w', newline='')
        with simMatrix:
             writer = csv.writer(simMatrix,delimiter=',')
             for x in range (0,len(data)):
                     result = data[x].tolist()
                     writer.writerow(result)

Other code:

```
                                 simMatrix = open(ficheroDestino, 'w',newline='')
                                 with simMatrix:
                                 writer = csv.writer(simMatrix,delimiter=',')
                                 for x in range (0,len(data)):
                                     result = data[x].tolist()
                                     result2 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in datos)
                                     result3 = datos2.split(" ")
                                     writer.writerow(result3)
```

I expect the output of my csv as:
1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

8 10 11 12

each number in a different column and row

Comment: what do you mean by the numbers in each sub-array aren't separated. What's the shape of data array ?

Comment: its just one item like [1 2 3 4 ]  for example: data[0] = [1 2 3 4] as one item, I want to separate this numbers llike [1, 2, 3, 4] and write it in a csv

Answer (score 1):

I would use Pandas DataFrame to_csv method. Following is a sample

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [["1 2 3 4"], ["5 6 7 8"], ["9 10 11 12"]]
pd.DataFrame(np.array([str(i).replace("['", "").replace("']", "").split(" ") for i in data])).to_csv("file.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just try `numpy.savetxt()`, example code is as below:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [5, 6, 7, 8],
                 [9, 10, 11, 12]]).astype(int)

np.savetxt('test.csv', data, fmt='%d', delimiter=' ')
```

The .csv file will be like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
    datas = pd.DataFrame(data)

    print(datas)
    datas.to_csv('./test.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: i tried this and it writes all in the first column for the row 1, for example row 1 and column 2 its empty